# solving recurrence T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2 - 1) + n/2 + 2

Tags: big-o, recurrence

Need some help on solving this runtime recurrence, using Big-Oh:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2 - 1) + n/2 + 2
```

I don't quite get how to use the Master Theorem here

Comment: Have you looked thoroughly at all of the questions that are listed on the right side of the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For n *big enough* you can assume `T(n/2 - 1) == T(n/2)`, so you can change

```
  T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2 - 1) + n/2 + 2
```

into

```
  T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + n/2 + 2
```

And use Master Theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) for

```
  T(n) = a*T(n/b) + f(n)

  a = 2
  b = 2
  f(n) = n/2 + 2
  c = 1 
  k = 0

  log(a, b) = 1 = c
```

and so you have (*case 2*, since `log(a, b) = c`)

```
  T(n) = O(n**c * log(n)**(k + 1))
  T(n) = O(n * log(n))
```

Comment: On the contrary, I find it not clear at all why "you can assume ..."

Comment: @hivert: Because the landau notation is used to describe the asymptotic behavior of a function and `(n/2 - 1)` and `(n/2)` are asymptotically equivalent: `lim n->inf (n/2 - 1) / (n/2) = 1`.

Comment: @CliffordVienna : The assumption is *not* `Theta(n/2 - 1) == Theta(n/2)` but `Theta(T(n/2 - 1)) == Theta(T(n/2))` which is clearly wrong for example if `T=exp`.

Comment: @hivert: you are right of course, but in this case T() clearly must have a polynomial upper bound because we get a solution with a polynomial upper bound for the slightly larger `T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + n/2 + 2`, thus `lim n->inf T(n/2 - 1) / T(n/2) = 1`. (obviously T() is positive monotonic and also otherwise reasonable friendly)